# Modelica, what's der(x)

Tags: graph, equation, modelica, derivative

in the modelica language I found the time derivative of x used in this equation:

der(x) = 1 - x

as always the x is set to 0 by default, what I don't understand is how this equation drives the value of x towards 1.0.

reached the 2 seconds mark, shouldn't it go to negative instead of stabilizing to 1.0?

source: https://mbe.modelica.university/behavior/equations/first_order/

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Calculus, time derivative of x (i.e. dx/dt (t0) ) represents the amount of increase or decrease of a variable as simulation proceeds at time point t0. Remember Taylor series expansion:

```
x(t0 + dt) = x(t0) + dx/dt(t0) . dt + O(dt^2)
```

So from this Calculus-based observation it is straightforward to see that:

- if `der(x) > 0`, then `x` will increase as the simulation runs and vise versa.
- `x` will increase as time increases but `der(x)` would decrease as x increases.
- As `der(x)` approaches 0, then the increase of `x` will slow down and x tends to 1.
- If the initial value of `x` is equal to 2, then `der(x) = -1` at the start of the simulation and it approaches 0 as time increases and meanwhile `x` approaches 1.
- If `x = 1`, then `der(x) = 0` and `x` would neither increase nor decrease. The value of `x = 1` is the steady-state of the given ODE system that makes `der(x) = 0`

Comment: I'm gonna revise Taylor's series then, that part is my Achille's heel!

Comment: can you tell me the difference between der(x) and x? I don't understand when does the x value change and according to what. The der(x) on the other hand has an equation so at least I know how and why it changes. Another thing I don't understand is, how x = 2, approaches 1, shouldn't x increase with time instead of decreasing? Or is it because of its relationship with der(x) that now is negative and therefore changes x's behavior?

Comment: As stated in the answer, der(x) is the time derivative of x. So if x corresponds to distance traveled, der(x) is the velocity.

Comment: Initially  (say at time t = 0 second) if x = 2, der(x) = 1 - 2 = -1 . So x will be decreasing.

Comment: Thank you for the distance-travel example that you wrote me, now I understand how they are releated to eachother and in turn how the whole system works! You used an "if" though, does that mean that there are other examples where x isn't the travelled distance but something else?

Comment: Infinitely many. For example if x corresponds to velocity of a particle, then der(x) is the acceleration